# Django get IP only returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a webserver set up with gunicorn and nginx and django.

I am accessing it remotely, and with this:

```
def testIP(request):
    ip_address = utils.get_ip(request)
```

I just keep getting an ip address of 127.0.0.1 Like i said I am accessing it remotely and thus it should not be giving a local address.

I think it might have something to do with gunicorn, but I want to check here first to see if you guys have any insights.

Comment: How are you connecting nginx to gunicorn?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How does get_ip() work?

If nginx is a reverse proxy and gunicorn is the app server, it's always getting requests from nginx on the local machine.

The real ip that nginx sends to the app server is in my case `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` via the nginx conf line `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`

So you might want to set that, and in your django app account for the different header by either using your new IP header or set `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` = `request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']`

Comment: @DantheMan: A different (perhaps better) idea is to use the reverse proxy middleware: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#reverse-proxy-middleware

Comment: @WoLpH -- cool! I didn't know they baked it in due to common use, but it looks like it was removed in 1.1?

Comment: you're right. It was removed because it might be dangerous if you don't verify your proxy server. But the original code is still available and works like a charm :)

Comment: @WoLpH the middleware was deprecated in Django 1.1 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1/#removed-setremoteaddrfromforwardedfor-middleware

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244217/checking-proxy-set-header-forwaded-by-nginx-reverse-proxy-django-app works for me. cause I use request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') in django