# GeoIP always shows the server's IP address

Tags: django, nginx, geoip

I am trying to use GeoIP, but I have a problem when I use REMOTE_ADDR. The IP shown is that of my server and not the client.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
Example context:
    g = GeoIP()
    ip = self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    context['my_ip'] = ip # this display ip client
    context['pais_anuncio'] = g.country_code('ip') # this display ip my server.
```

What am I doing wrong, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, since you are passing the *string* `'ip'`, it is defaulting to your server's IP. Try passing in the variable `ip`, like this:

```
context['pais_anuncio'] = g.country_code(ip)
```

Comment: My guess is that since he's using nginx, he has to set the `X-Real-IP` , as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512341/django-get-ip-only-returns-127-0-0-1. That's why I marked it as a duplicate of that question.