# Reliably get client IP for HTTPS request in django?

Tags: django, http-headers

Is there a way to reliably get client's IP in Django if the request is via HTTPS? For instance, is the data available in `request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']` secure against spoofing and other attacks?

In my case `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']=='10.0.0.132'` which is an internal IP. So I could rely on `request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']`  or `request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` only.

My site is on pythonanywhere.com, if that matters.

So, is there a reliable client IP in `request.META` via HTTPS?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512341/django-get-ip-only-returns-127-0-0-1

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta thanks, I read that and similar discussions. However, none of them elaborates whether that information is secure in case of HTTPS or not.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/can-i-trust-the-source-ip-of-an-http-request looks very close to the answer...
And this one - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14516/ip-spoofing-a-threat?noredirect=1&lq=1